# How do I inject OpenTelemetry Jaeger traces on an external .Net WebAPI project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, open-telemetry, jaeger

Is there a way to inject OpenTelemetry Jaeger traces to a WebAPI endpoints via a package?

I have a requirement to add tracing logic to an existing WebAPI project but the tracing logic *should be invoked by the target WebAPI via an external package*.

At a high level the workflow should be as follows:

1. Class library implements a method that *generates traces on a specific Assembly, for a specific endpoint and specific method*. Ideally the method should accept an argument that represents the calling Assembly (plus associated endpoint and method)
2. Bundle the class library via `dotnet pack --configuration Release`
3. Distribute the package, ideally as a DLL (or similar) in a given assembly.
4. When a request begins on an Assembly/WebAPI project, the project should invoke the
   tracing logic via the package
5. Tracing should execute for the entirety of the request and a complete trace generated e.g
   e.g Activity.Kind

Currently I have the following code which configures OpenTelemetry and Jaeger tracing on a .Net Console application:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly ActivitySource MyActivitySource = new(
      "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyLibrary");
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .AddSource("MyCompany.MyProduct.MyLibrary")
            .ConfigureResource(res => res.AddService(serviceName: "consoletest"))
            .AddConsoleExporter()
             .AddJaegerExporter(o =>
                   {
                    o.AgentHost = "localhost";
                    o.AgentPort = 6831;
                    o.Endpoint = new Uri("localhost:14268");
                    o.Protocol = JaegerExportProtocol.UdpCompactThrift;
                  })
            .Build();
        using (var activity = MyActivitySource.StartActivity("SayHello"))
        {
            activity?.SetTag("foo", 1);
            activity?.SetTag("bar", "Hello, World!");
            activity?.SetTag("baz", new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
            activity?.SetStatus(ActivityStatusCode.Ok);
        }    
            System.Console.WriteLine("Traces are being created and exported " +
                  "to Console in the background. " +
                  "Press ENTER to stop.");
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When the program runs it displays the trace in console output as below:

```
Activity.TraceId:            de3ee31efa3f2fada0bd33160a140b38
Activity.SpanId:             f0cf1e02b260439d
Activity.TraceFlags:         Recorded
Activity.ActivitySourceName: MyCompany.MyProduct.MyLibrary
Activity.DisplayName:        SayHello
Activity.Kind:               Internal
Activity.StartTime:          2023-07-04T07:01:06.8191208Z
Activity.Duration:           00:00:00.0008447
Activity.Tags:
    foo: 1
    bar: Hello, World!
    baz: [1,2,3]
StatusCode: Ok
Resource associated with Activity:
    service.name: consoletest
    service.instance.id: 53f432fb-bf5d-4f48-a330-fb7ddc6aa790
    telemetry.sdk.name: opentelemetry
    telemetry.sdk.language: dotnet
    telemetry.sdk.version: 1.5.0
```

*I would like to reuse this logic in the class library project.*
I'm not sure of the exact methods in the OpenTelemetry SDK to achieve this but I have tried the following for a sample target Assembly (not tested !):

```
using MyCompany.MyProduct.MyLibrary; 
// Import the namespace from the packaged Class library 

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    private readonly HttpClient _factory;
    private readonly ActivitySource _activitySource;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, HttpClient factory, ActivitySource activitySource)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _factory = factory;
        _activitySource = activitySource;
    }

    [HttpGet("OutgoingHttp")]
    public async Task OutgoingHttpRequest()
    {
        string methodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;

        // Generate traces using the injected ActivitySource
        using (var activity = _activitySource.StartActivity(methodName))
        {
            var response = await _factory.GetAsync("https://code-maze.com");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the following versions:

WebAPI project - .Net 7

Class library project - .NET Standard 2.0 framework

OpenTelemetry :

- dotnet add package OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console --version 1.5.0
- dotnet add package OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting --version 1.5.0
- dotnet add package OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger --version 1.5.0

My questions:

1. Is this the **correct** way ? registering a "listener" on ActivitySource which "listens" on a request.

2.If yes, how can I sort of *dynamically* start the trace each time a request comes on a method. Essentially I don't want to inject the `using{}` block on each method. They are many methods and it would add to overall complexity of the solution.

3. If the solution above is wrong which methods can I use from the OpenTelemetry library to achieve this.

PS: I have technical constraints in my WebAPI projects and the tracing middleware cannot be implemented inside them.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a couple of things here.

You don't add tracing as middleware. All packages like ASP.NET produce `Activity` objects under a specific `ActivitySource` names. It's up to you to add an `ActivityListener` for that name inside the same AppDomain.

With that in mind, you can create a tracer anywhere, you only need the main code to execute something on your dll to make that work. How you get your main WebApi to run a method on your new class is more of a .NET problem than OpenTelemetry one.

In terms of having it only produce `Activity` objects for a specific path/route, you need to look at Samplers and create a sampler that discards any `Activity` objects that don't match the routes you're looking for. That sampler would then be added to your Tracing setup.

Keep in mind that if you add tracing twice, you will get duplicates sent, so you need to ensure that there is only 1 `TracerProvider` listening on the same sources, sending to that exporter.

Small sidenote, Jaeger from 1.47 onwards has builtin support for the OpenTelemetry Protocol, so you should switch to using the OpenTelemetryProtocol exporter rather than the Jaeger one.